# Yii2 unset post request array after save

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have post array as

```
Yii::$app->request->post()
```

How can I unset this request array after performing insert operation , but before rendering the view

Comment: Do you really need this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this :

```
Yii::$app->request->bodyParams = [];
```

Read more about [`$bodyParams`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html#$bodyParams-detail).